# Why don't answer my question newly?

Tags: discussion, questions

I put some question and one of set 200 boundary for one of them, I know  some of users really can help me but dont answer my question while they are spend time and answer newbie user question,why behavior inimically to my questions?

Comment: One of the problems I personally have with your questions is the language you are using. Not so good punctuation, sentences hard to understand etc. Like just here above. It's really hard (for me) to read them. Also, you use popular but meaningless statements, like *"I try below code but not work :("* [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/101955/16495). Does not work? What it did? What it was supposed to do? So, I'm not ignoring you because it's you, it simply looks like **I really was ignoring your questions** - because they was unpleasant to read and hard to understand.

Comment: @Bala your language cleanup edit would be precious on main site, but here on meta it only hides an important aspect directly related to the question asked.

Comment: @Mołot I will rollback it, I just doubt during the edit and  If you can help with this question, please improve it.

Comment: I guess reputation is not just a number. In my very short time here you have addressed some very unconstructive comments in an aggressive manner and you harness every opportunity that an existing good answer does not have enough time to be improved in lights of new comments.

Answer (score 6):

> why behavior inimically to my questions ?

I'm sorry, but that's utter nonsense. If you have some proof that people are acting in an aggressive manner towards you, please provide it, or flag for moderator involvement. Don't blindly presume that because your question hasn't been answered, that you're somehow being victimised. These sort of false accusations are, ironically, the simplest way to ensure that people *will* deliberately ignore your questions in the future.

If you think that your question has not received enough attention, **improve it**. Simple as that. There is not a long queue of people here waiting to ignore you for the thrill of it; if someone knows the answer to the question, as you've posed it, and has time to answer it sufficiently, then they will answer you.

If no-one answers you, then the question is not clear enough, or nobody who knows the answer, or who has time to answer you, has seen it yet. The bounty you have placed is to get extra attention to the question, **not** to guarantee you an answer, expediently or otherwise.

On a separate, but related, matter, please don't answer your own questions with things like

> the post updatedthe post updatedthe post updatedthe post updatedthe post updatedthe post updatedthe post updated

just to get them bumped up to the front page. This is very bad form, and completely against the rules, which you know (otherwise you wouldn't have immediately deleted that same answer). Also, don't randomly ping users who you think might be able to help you, it's very annoying.

Comment: thanks for your attention ,but after spend much time in here and read answers I know some user able to answer my question. it was bad idea to get to front page my question and I am so sorry to did it because my problem is very urgency and I dont know anyone that can reply it, because ask in drupalstack in hope to answered,:(

Comment: @zhilevan language cleanup edits will bump your questions to the front page just as well, and are legal, encouraged! So you can get the benefit of a bump without breaking the rules, and it will actually increase your chance to get an answer.